# Нужно пояснение одной строки

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, и не могу в интернете найти как работает строка `var exp = (o>4), o = o%5, str = pangrams[+exp][o];`. Поясните - кто знает, и как гуглить?

```js
var pangrams = [ 
  // not pangrams:
    [ 
      "This isn't a pangram!",
      "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz ",
      "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "Detect Pangram",
      "A pangram is a sentence that contains every single letter of the alphabet at least once."
    ],
  
  // pangrams:
    [
      "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz",
      "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.",
      "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.",
      "ABCD45EFGH,IJK,LMNOPQR56STUVW3XYZ",
      "AbCdEfGhIjKlM zYxWvUtSrQpOn"
    ]
  ];

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].forEach(function(o){
  var exp = (o>4), o = o%5, str = pangrams[+exp][o]; // как работает дання строка и что она делает?
  console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: Это писал какой-то извращенец. Но ничего сложно нет. Возьмите ручку и бумажку и посчитайте значение каждой переменной

Comment: В этой строке написаны три выражения. Обычно их пишут на разных строках и через ;

Comment: @AlexeyTen 1 - Условие, 2 - Вычисление и 3- Вычисление. Они между собой как то связаны ? Ну к примеру вычисления происходят только если условие верно?

Comment: Нет, вычисление просходит всегда.

Comment: Там нет условий. Там три вычисления. `(o > 4)` возвращает значение true или false и оно присваивается переменной exp

Comment: "Оператор запятая". Просто её почти нигде не используют) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, в данном случае - не оператор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  // parameter o (array item) is 6
  var exp = o > 4; // exp is true
  o = o % 5; // o is 1
  var str = pangrams[exp? 1 : 0][o]; // str is "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.",
```

Comment: спасибо большое;

Answer (score 2):

`exp = (o>4)` - в exp возвращается true или false, в зависимости от того, больше o 4 или нет.

`o = o%5` - вычисление [остатка от деления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC).

`str = pangrams[+exp][o]` - exp преобразуется в числовое значение 0 или 1, далее в str возвращается элемент массива `pangrams` по указанным ключам exp и o.